# Creating a File and writing to a MIFARE DESFire EV1 card

Tags: nfc, mifare

I am using TAPLINX sdk to write to a MIFARE DESFire EV1 card. By now I have set a key and am able to validate the key. Next , I would like to create a file and store small data in there. I do not see detailed API description in any of their documentation. Kindly Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use the below github project for code related to creating an application and writing to a file in a MIFARE DESFire card.
https://github.com/dfpalomar/TapLinxSample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/nxp/sampletaplinx/MainActivity.java